# UEFI Dual boot not recognizing windows 7 partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Been messing around with Ubuntu, I actually installed it as my only OS but since my graphics card(AMD) kinda sucks on linux(For gaming purposes) -  I have to have a windows partition.

However, dual-booting simply won't work out for me. I currently installed a fresh copy of Windows 7.. That's fine. When I run the Ubuntu installer, it just doesn't recognize Windows 7. I'm left with wiping the entire hard disk and installing only Ubuntu, or basically nothing else(well, there is the "something else", but it doesn't recognize windows either).

What do I do? It's a problem with the new UEFI bios as far as I understand, right?

I tried booting from both USB/SD and CD/DVD with the same result, so I suppose something is up with the file structure or the UEFI/legacy booting. But before I mess with the BIOS, I'd like a pointer to what I should do exactly? I've tried shrinking my hard drive into a 200GB partition which I thought Ubuntu would recognize(and then install on), but it only recognizes all 1TB I have..?
Thanks in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFgGr.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRQqJ.jpg

Comment: Did you install windows with uei enabled?  Did you then run boot-repair?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu has two separate modes, and so does Windows. You need to boot both by selecting their EFI boot files under the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: @Zacharee1 How would I exactly go about doing so? I'm using the MSI updated BIOS with gui etc.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Not sure, I think I did install with UEFI enabled. How do I boot repair?

Comment: I don't have one of those computers, so I'm not sure, but there might be a `boot from EFI file` option, or something like that.

Comment: Also, the bad graphics performance you're getting might be from a driver problem (not a stupid generic suggestion; this is real). Did you install `fglrx-updates` (the proprietary driver for AMD graphics)?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Can't find it, so I don't think so? I only can choose between LEGACY or UEFI+LEGACY mode?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I have an AMD Radeon HD7900 card.. as far as i've read it just plain sucks on linux destro. I tried the AMD catalyst driver and it was not good.

Comment: What did you install, exactly, and where did you get what you installed?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. Burned the .iso to a dvd. Same with Ubuntu.

Comment: No, lol. I meant the AMD driver for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Zacharee1 AMD catalyst driver?

Comment: I guess. Where'd you get it (exact link)?

Comment: The normal AMD catalyst driver doesn't work.

Comment: I used this guide to install it: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gIL-LQggVH4 I have however heard AMD gpus suck on Ubuntu for gaming.. My fps in dota was lower than 30 whereas in windows it's stable 120

Comment: SOLVED.
I manually created a partition in the Windows disk management, shrinking my main hard drive down without assigning anything to it after. This was registered in the Ubuntu installation, and I chose the "something else" option and installed it on there. I needed to run boot-repair to mess with the Grub2 booting, but not I have a dual-boot system with both Ubuntu and WIndows 7.